# execut code directly after you have logged on into your computer

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, my-site

Is it possible to automate a SharePoint related activity so that it gets executed soon after  you have logged on into a computer?

What I want is creating an user MySite directly after the user has logged on into the computer (before browsing to mySite).

Answer (score 1):

The MySite (site collection actually) gets created for the user automatically if he doesn't have one already (provided he has the rights to have one). Is enough for the user to navigate to this page _layouts/mysite.aspx (e.g. assuming your MySite Host with "personal" being the mapped path) then using  http://mySiteHost/_layouts/mysite.aspx would automatically create site everytime user navigates to the page OR if he has one, it will redirect to http://mySitesHost/personal/username - "username" also depends on how you configured in UPSA.

If you really want to execute code upon computer launch, you need also to account for Login, because if don't have Kerberos Enabled it would ask user to authenticate!

It would be enough to have the default page in your browser ?

C:\Marius

Comment: thanks for your answer, I don't understand exactly what you meant with "you need also to account for Login" 
is it possible to exectue a code upon computer launch to create my site for user who logs on?

Comment: Of course you can, use Logon Scripts for that (e.g. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758918(v=ws.10).aspx). By "Login" I actually meant the Login Prompt when navigating to the SharePoint site that usually one receives. You could create the My Site using something similar http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saurabhkv/archive/2008/09/29/how-to-create-mysite-programmatically.aspx